# Why does the For Loop not work when I run it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this for loop to run correctly but it is just not. The objects inside of the loop don't run and I don't understand why.

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    wordFound = Math.floor(Math.Random());
    document.write(wordFound);
    wordData = [wordFound];

    if (wordFound != wordFound.indexOf(wordData)) {
        document.write('Words being generated...');
    } else {
        document.write('Words being generated...');
    }   
}
```

Comment: it is `Math.random()`

Comment: Check your browser console and see what message(s) you see?

Comment: `wordFound` shouldn't have an `indexOf` method. Even if it were backwards, the search doesn't make sense. You previously define `wordFound` as part of `wordData` so it will always be true. It also doesn't make sense that your conditional branches do the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but this ' wordFound.indexOf(wordData)' will also trow an error.

Answer (score 8):

`Math.Random()` is not a function, should be **[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)**.

Also `wordFound` is not a string or array so you can't use `indexOf()`.

**NOTE :** `Math.floor(Math.random())` will always return `O`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`wordMeta.indexOf(wordFound))`
Array has method indexOf ,if u want get the position of wordMeta in work Found,you should use method like this code what I had write.